# no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('OK') in Spring REST Docs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-restdocs

I have a springBoot 2.1.9.RELEASE application that uses Spring REST Docs.

I have this method in my TestController that returns  `ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>` ( HttpStatus.OK)

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/reservation-event")
                .content(convertToString(reservation))
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(document("create-reservation-event",
```

but when I run the test I got this error :

```
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.ModelCreationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('OK')
 at [Source: (byte[])""OK""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I have changed to `.andExpect(status().isCreated())` and the return type to `return ok().body(HttpStatus.CREATED);` but then I got this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :201
Actual   :200
```

Comment: Looks like `convertToString(reservation)` this is returning `OK` make the response this method works. Because the content tries to deserialize a `OK` as s tring.

Comment: I debug and this part is OK, and there is no return in that object

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the exception please?